# Maximized windows in Windows show odd dead space

Tags: windows-10

So we have experienced this a couple of times, on multiple PCs running Windows. We have only experienced this with one program, but it has occurred over multiple versions of the same program (i.e. 2017, 2018, etc.).

When we maximise the program window, the top of the window will go grey, and become "uninteractable" - that is, when you click on it, nothing happens, and right-clicking brings up the desktop pop up menu.

[image]

If we restore the window, the toolbar reappears, even if it gets stretched out to the screen borders (without maximizing it).

Is this a Windows thing?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the problem occurs only with this particular program, than more than likely the problem is the program itself.  I would suspect the developer of the application has made a mistake in designing  (not programming) the application, which is causing it to behave in this manner.  Other factors can be involved such as customization of your OS on your end, such as screen scaling.  However, ultimately that application is the only one with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a graphics/display issue - do you have a multiple monitor display?

I had the same problem today and fixed it by changing the screen resolution and then changing it back again.

See HERE: http://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2018/08/maximized-window-get-blank-empty-space-with-multi-monitors-in-windows-10.html